# Metadata not showing in tab Next.js 13.4.1

Tags: reactjs, next.js, metadata

I have defined the metadata object as you'll see below but it doesn't show in my chrome tab, it only shows "localhost:3000/#home". All my .jsx files are marked with "use client" bc it's a portfolio I'll be uploading to Github Pages so I can't use Server Components. I don't know if that has something to do with it.

Here's my layout.jsx:

```
"use client"

import './globals.css'
import { Exo_2, Bruno_Ace } from 'next/font/google'
import Navbar from '@/components/Navbar'
import { AnimatePresence } from 'framer-motion';


 const exo_2 = Exo_2({
  subsets: ['latin'],
  variable: '--font-body',
  display: 'swap'
 })

 const bruno_ace = Bruno_Ace({
  subsets: ['latin'],
  variable: '--font-nav',
  weight: '400',
  display: 'swap'
 })

export const metadata = {
  title: 'Inti Silva',
  description: 'Portfolio Front-end Inti Tomas Silva',
}

export default function RootLayout({children}) {

  return (

    <html lang="en" className={`${exo_2.variable} ${bruno_ace.variable}`}>
      <body>
        <Navbar />
        <AnimatePresence>
        {children}
        </AnimatePresence>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

I tried putting the metadata object in my page.jsx but it doesn't show either. I'm using the new app directory that it's supposed to be stable in this version.

My root page.jsx:

```
"use client"

import About from '../components/About';
import Contact from '../components/Contact';
import Main from '../components/Main';
import Projects from '../components/Projects';
import Skills from '../components/Skills';
import Transitions from '@/components/Transitions';



export default function Home() {
  return (
        <>
        <Transitions/>
        <Main />
        <About />
        <Skills />
        <Projects />
        <Contact />
        </>
  );
};
```

Comment: That's only for server components, for client components you still use the old way

Answer (score 5):

Both static and dynamic metadata (generateMetadata) are only supported in server components. You can read more from the docs [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/metadata).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34827807)

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is that you need to separate Pages and Components, A page should not contain any react logic, like useState etc. but a Component should.

> A component should have **"use client"** but a page shouldn't.

This way you can create and use the NextJS's metadata object to define title and metadata. Now Metadata is created by next on the page component and it cannot have "use client".

In the above example, you are creating the layout with "use client", remove that. Secondly, split components and pages. Example:

```
//page.js
import ContactForm from "@/components/ContactForm";

export const metadata = {
    title: "My Awesome App",
    description: "Nice Description"
}

export default function Page() {
    return (
        <ContactForm />
    )
}
```

> 

```
//ContactForm.js
"use client";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function ContactForm() {
    const [myState, setMyState] = useState("Hi");

    return (
        <div>
            {myState}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, i fixed it just removing the 'use client' from my layout.tsx and the title starts showing up

Comment: How long did it take to update for you?

Answer (score 0):

Well, by marking everything with "use client" you end up defeating the purpose of the Next.js framework.

Before going into details of your implementation, I want to point out that you can deploy Next apps for free on Vercel ([vercel.com/new](https://vercel.com/new)). It's extremely simple and you can do a lot of stuff. I cannot recommend it enough.

Now for your meta tags, your root layout component **[has to be a server component.](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts#root-layout-required)** When the server builds your application it has to render your initial layout on the server side because that is what is going to hold the rest of the application.

When a crawler, a bot, or even a user, access your site that pre-rendered layout component is sent as plain HTML to start up the application while CSS and JS load.

In React we have the head tags hard-coded in the index.html. Then after the JS downloads and kicks in it can manipulate the tags to generate dynamic page titles. However, the initial page title is the same **regardless of which user-side route you're on** because the head tag comes from the original index.html.

On the other hand, the first time a visitor access your website, Next will send them an HTML file that was created with the correct head tags in the server. That's where the "metadata" object comes into play.

The "metadata" object is used by Next to build the head tags that are supposed to accompany that route.

When your layout component is rendered on the server, Next knows that that object is supposed to be used when building that specific route.

However, if the layout or page is marked as a client component, you're telling Next that the code of that component is to be executed and rendered on the client.

So when someone accesses the page, they won't see a title because the title did not exist in the HTML file that was downloaded.

When the JavaScript finishes downloading and start running the metadata object is something that means nothing to React.

For navigation bars, headers, and footers, which are the most common components in the root layout, when you need a component that is interactive/dynamic, you can make that specific compontent a "use client" component. For example, instead of the navbar, make the button that opens up the menu a client component.

I really recommend deploying a full Next app instead of a React SPA on GitHub. I use Vercel for free, but there are many other options.

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT)

Comment: @mainak well, it wasn't. Been learning Next.js for the past couple of weeks and everything I wrote is what I learned through trial and error while building my portfolio. Want the link and/or further details on the differences between client and server components? Or maybe... I don't know, give a better answer?